# The progress bar runs smooth while uploading a file

Tags: php, jquery, iis-7

I'm facing a strange problem :
The progress bar during update does not show gradual progress but stands still for a long time and then jumps to a much higher complete percentage at once.

I'm using php and jquery and as  a server IIS7 .

The same code runs perfectly on iss6.

I find an answer in the following link : http://www.logaholic.com/help/22/why-doesnt-the-progress-bar-runs-smooth-while-updating but it didn't work for me

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more information. the jqueryui progressbar doesn't move on it's own, therefore you must have implemented something that changes it's progress value. Without us seeing that logic we can't help you.

Comment: Wait ... you're running a PHP site on IIS? ... ¡Por Que?

Comment: yes... iis can serve php... why is that surprising?

Comment: Just because it can doesn't mean it should. I mean, a 600lbs woman can wear speedos ... doesn't mean she should. :=P I'm well aware IIS runs PHP on `php-cgi.exe`, however, with windows apps being kernel executions, you could run into difficulty in performance if running other 3rd party apps on same system. Not to mention the cost difference. I know it's possible, I just don't know why anyone would do it?